# Help with interpreting the physical meaning of the gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

I understand that the physical meaning of the gradient is a vector in the direction of maximum increase with the magnitude equivalent to the maximum rate of change. However, I'm simply not seeing it. Is there a good way of visualizing this?

Here is my thinking, which I am visualizing to be a counter example to the interpretation of the gradient. I'm not sure on how to graph this, so I'll explain in words. Assume a function T = x + y, where it is constant in the Z dimension (which allows me to put the T function on the z-axis). At the origin, the function increases equally and the most in both the x direction and the y direction, but along the line of y = x, the function decreases the most.

The gradient of this function at the origin, is the vector addition of the increase in the x direction and increase in the y direction. How then is the vector pointing in $T = <x, y>$ which is along the line of y = x, equivalent to the direction of maximum increase?

Comment: $T(x,y,z) = x+y$ would only be only be plottable in $4$d and wouldn't be constant in $z$.  However, if you mean $T(x,y) = x + y$, then that is plottable in $3$d where $z = T(x,y)$.  But again, it's not constant in $z$.

Comment: think of a map that has the height contours - the gradient is the direction of the steepest change, up or down. As example, an electrical field has a direction in which the voltage change is highest.

Comment: The gradient of [this function](http://archives.math.utk.edu/ICTCM/VOL10/C009/dd.gif) points "uphill" and has magnitude equal to the slope of the line in that direction.

Comment: @Bye_World T(x,y,z) where z is constant is the same thing as T(x,y), right?

Comment: @Bye_World That link you gives isn't the example that I am visualizing. I'm wondering what's wrong with my example.

Comment: @Goldname To your first comment: No.  They are different.  To your seoncd: I know that the image wasn't your exact function, I just found an image on Google Images that I thought might illustrate the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Consider two isotimic surfaces $u=c_1$ and $u=c_2$. Now consider the line of shortest distance between these two surfaces. The *length* of this line is the *magnitude* and its *direction* vector from the lower surface to the higher surface gives the *direction* of the **gradient vector**.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by a surface u = c1 and v = c2? How is that a surface?

Comment: Are you aware of the cartesian co-ordinates? What is $x=0$ or $y=0$?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now. But the partial derivative of any one of those surfaces is a tangent to that surface, so I don't see how the gradient vector of those two gives the shortest distance between the surface.

Comment: So you want a proof? Check this. http://mathinsight.org/directional_derivative_gradient_derivation

Comment: Not a proof. just something to visualize this. and also to figure out what's wrong with my specific example

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to look at it, if you accept [directional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) (also has a nice illustration of the gradient).

Suppose we are interested in the direction of greatest increase of some $f(x,y)$. Then, by definition we should look at the rate of increase of $f$ in the direction $v$ via its directional derivative:
$$ R_f(v) = \nabla f\cdot \hat{v} $$
which is the rate of change of $f$ in the direction $v$. Intuitively, this is because you are *projecting the total change (i.e. the gradient) of $f$ onto the direction vector $v$*. It might be obvious that $R_f(v)$ is maximal when $v=\nabla f$, but you can easily see this by letting $$ \hat{v} = (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)) = \frac{(v_1,v_2)}{||(v_1,v_2)||_2} = \frac{v}{||v||_2}$$
so that (in 2D) $R_f(v) = \cos(\theta)\partial_xf + \sin(\theta)\partial_yf$. Notice that $\theta$ is simply the angle with the $x$ axis in the plane, so it determines the direction fully. Let's find the maximal $\theta$. Take $\partial_\theta R_f(v) = 0$ and you'll find $\theta=\arctan(\partial_y f/\partial_x f)$, which means $v = (v_1,v_2) = (\partial_x f, \partial_y f)=\nabla f$, as we expected. I.e. $ \max_v R_f(v) = (\nabla f\cdot \nabla f)/||\nabla f||_2 = ||\nabla f||_2 $. So the direction of maximal $R_f$ is $\nabla f$.

---

Ok, well for your specific example, $T(x,y)=x+y$, so $\nabla T = (1,1)$.
How can we see that walking along the gradient gives the greatest increase?
Let's just take a *unit* step (from the origin) in a few different directions to see why. Note that $T(0,0)=0$

First, in the $x$ direction, we take a step $s=(1,0)$, so $T(s)=1$. So we took a step of size $1$, and $T$ increased by 1.

Let's try in the $y$ direction: $s=(0,1)$, thus $T(s)=1$, so same as last time.

What about $s=(1,1)/\sqrt{2}$, which is a *unit* step in the gradient direction?
Well, $T(s)=\sqrt{2} > 1$. So even though we took a step of size $1$, our function grew about ${\sim}{1.4}$, rather than just by $1$, as it did in the other directions.

What about something in between? Say, $s=(0.921,0.395)$, so then $T(s)=1.316$. So, taking a step of size $1$ led to an increase of ${\sim}1.3$. This is between the other values, as we would kind of expect.